# Random number generator in java using seed

Tags: java

I am unable to generate different set of random numbers in my code.

[image]

For 2 different simulations my code gives 2 sets of random numbers.
I am also unable to understand the use of seed.

Comment: Please post your actual code here rather than a screenshot. What is your actual question?

Comment: If you specify a seed, you will get the same sequence of numbers between runs. The normal implementation of random makes it so that the seed is dependent on the time it is ran at. (So different at any time). If you however specify a seed, it starts it random number gen from that number, and you'll get the same numbers every time.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code, i should be j....

```
for (j = 0; j < digits.size(); j++) {
    System.out.println(digits.get(i));  // <=== i should be j.
}
```

I'd never mix i and j... and keep variables scoped to loops if possible.

```
for (int index = 0; index < digits.size(); index++) {
    System.out.println(digits.get(index));
}
```

and... if you're simply wanting to print results... consider `java.util.Arrays.toString(int [] array)`

Comment: I am getting same random number for 1 iteration. I have understood the use of seed.